# Class not found, composer and Zend Framework 1 autoloader issue

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4, psr-0

I have the following class autoload definition in a `[root]/composer.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "": [
        "application/models",
        "application/controllers",
        "application/forms",
        "library/"
      ]
    },
    "psr-4": {
      "": ["src/"]
    },
    "classmap": [
      "app/AppKernel.php",
      "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

When I call the `[root]/public_html/index.php` page I got the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'classes\DependencyInjection' not found in /var/www/html/application/bootstrap.php:29

What's in `[root]/public_html/index.php` is the following code:

```
$bootstrap = true;
require_once '../application/bootstrap.php';
```

And what's in `[root]/application/bootstrap.php` file is:

```
// turn on autoloading for classes
// composer autoloader
include(MMIPATH.'/vendor/autoload.php');

// zend autoload
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$diContainer = new classes\DependencyInjection(services.yaml');
$proxy       = $diContainer->get('containerProxy');
```

This is the definition of `[root]/library/classes/DependencyInjection.php`:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
USE Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class DependencyInjection extends ContainerBuilder
{
    ....
}
```

What's wrong here? Why autoloader can't find that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to load a "classes" namespace, however your class is not defined as being in the "classes" namespace.

`new classes\DependencyInjection(...)` in PSR-0 loads `{paths}\classes\DependencyInjection.php` and attempts to instantiate the class `DependencyInjection` from the namespace `classes`, but `DependencyInjection` is not in the `classes` namespace. The file will load but the class does not exist.

You could add `namespace classes;` to each of these classes, but that's not exactly a good solution. Better solution is to use proper namespacing or change your PSR-0 list to include library/classes and use `new DependencyInjection(...)`. (My vote is for the first one -- use proper namespaces.)

As requested. example:

File Location
`{app}\library\UsefullNamespace\DependencyInjection.php`

Call it using
`new UsefullNamespace\DependencyInjection.php`

DependencyInjection.php:

```
namespace UsefullNamespace;  

use [...];  

class DependencyInjection extends ContainerBuilder
{
```

Comment: Also... don't use ZF1 if you don't absolutely have to. It's completely deprecated/end-of-life/no longer being maintained.

Comment: can you add some examples? of both solutions?

Comment: added -- the alternative is not really a solution, may not even work with PSR-0 (not sure). A useful namespace is something that actually makes sense to use for your app.